# Can winding number be calculated given a vector of points (samples of a curved line)?

Tags: geometry, analysis, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

Assume we have $X=[\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}]$, where, $\mathbf{x}=x_1,x_2,...$ and $\mathbf{y}=y_1,y_2,...$, representing a curve (sampled) in Cartesian coordinates. The question is whether or not we can find out the winding number by only using $X$?

Comment: Without more information/assumptions, no. The function could get arbitrarily 'windy' at the uncountably many other points that have not been sampled.

Comment: If you assume that you connect these points via straight line segments, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I found a MATLAB code that does the job very well. It is written in a way that the steps are easy to follow algorithmically:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13351-fast-and-robust-self-intersections/content/selfintersect.m